# Which of the following statements are true (CSIR)?

Tags: general-topology

**Let $\tau$ be the topolgy on $\mathbb R$ for which the interval [a,b), $-\infty<a<b<\infty$ form a base. Let $\sigma$ be topolgy on R such that $\tau \subseteq \sigma$ . Then**

1.Either $\sigma = \tau$ or $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.

2.If, moreover, the map x $\mapsto$ -x is continous for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.

3.If, moreover, the map x $\mapsto$ -x is homeomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.

4.If, moreover, the map x $\mapsto$ |x| is homeomorphism for $\sigma$, then $\sigma$ is the discrete topology.

Comment: What have you tried? It is better to have your insight to the problem to be included and in that case it would be easier to answer..

Comment: I have tried using definition of descrete topology , but i could not find any way to solve this problem . please give me hint to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = -x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $$f^{-1}[[a,b)] = \{ x: a \le f(x) < b \} = \{x: a \le -x < b \} = \{x: -b < x \le -a\} = (-b, -a]$$

So if $f$ is continuous on $\sigma$ with $\tau \subset \sigma$, all sets $[a,b)$ are in $\sigma$ (as they are in $\tau$) and so are all sets of the form $(c,d]$, by the above equation.

What can we say if *both* $[a,b)$ and $(c, a]$ are open?

(added : ) we can add one more open set $O_0 = \{0\}$, say, and show that the topology generated by $\tau \cup \{O_0\}$ is a proper superset of $\tau$ which is not discrete. This would show that 1. is false. As to 4.: the function $g: x \mapsto |x|$ is not injective so can never be a homeomorphism. And a false statement implies anything, so purely from a logical perspective the statement "if $g$ is a homeomorphism, $\sigma$ is discrete" would be true...

Comment: What is the counter example for ist part. Thank you for your prompt reply.